# How do I submit data to a hidden form field rather than submitting it on DOM?

Tags: javascript, digital-signature, signature, electronic-signature

Okay so I'm having some trouble here. I'm new to JS so my experience with Javascript is vague. I'm trying to submit a signature to a hidden element on the form I have set up. Right now, all it's doing is submitting it to the page itself as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUv4o.png)

I want it to where it posts to the form data as a hidden element so when it sends the data, it will upload it as an image.

Below is the code I have right now:

signature.js:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const form = document.querySelector('.signform');
const clearButton = document.querySelector('.clear-button');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
let writingMode = false;

const handlePointerDown = (event) => {
writingMode = true;  
ctx.beginPath();  
const [positionX, positionY] = getCursorPosition(event);  
ctx.moveTo(positionX, positionY);
}
const handlePointerUp = () => {  writingMode = false;}
const handlePointerMove = (event) => {  if (!writingMode) return  
const [positionX, positionY] = getCursorPosition(event);  ctx.lineTo(positionX, positionY);  ctx.stroke();}
const getCursorPosition = (event) => {  positionX = event.clientX - event.target.getBoundingClientRect().x;  positionY = event.clientY - event.target.getBoundingClientRect().y;  
return [positionX, positionY];
}
ctx.lineWidth = 2;
ctx.lineJoin = ctx.lineCap = 'round';
form.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {  event.preventDefault();
  const imageURL = canvas.toDataURL();  
  const image = document.createElement('img');  image.src = imageURL;  image.height = canvas.height;  image.width = canvas.width;  image.style.display = 'block';  form.appendChild(image);  clearPad();})

const clearPad = () => {  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);}
clearButton.addEventListener('click', (event) => {  event.preventDefault();  clearPad();})
canvas.addEventListener('pointerdown', handlePointerDown, {passive: true});
canvas.addEventListener('pointerup', handlePointerUp, {passive: true});
canvas.addEventListener('pointermove', handlePointerMove, {passive: true});
```

previewlease.php:

```
<p align='center'>Landlord Signature:</p>
   <center><canvas height="100" width="300" class="signature-pad"></canvas>    
   <p><a href="#" class="clear-button">Clear</a></p>    
   <input type="hidden" name="signature" /></center><br>
<button class='btn btn-primary'>Submit to Tenant</button>
```

I want to be able to let the code submit to the  `<input type="hidden" name="signature" />` then have it post it on the next page.

Any idea I need to do to be able to make this possible?

I tried changing this but it didn't work:

```
  const imageURL = canvas.toDataURL();
  //const image = document.createElement('img');  
  //image.src = imageURL;  image.height = canvas.height;  image.width = canvas.width;  image.style.display = 'block';  
  const input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");

    input.setAttribute("name", "signature");
    input.setAttribute("value", imageURL);

document.getElementById("signform").appendChild(input);
```

Comment: you want to upload the image when you submit the form?

Comment: Yes that's what I am wanting to do.

Comment: the signature is on the canvas?

Comment: @Unmitigated  No nothing in the console. I even checked the web server's error logs and nothing was thrown on there either. When I checked the source code on the inspect element, it still shows an empty hidden field with no value.

Comment: @mattrichards when I draw in the canvas, it shows the drawing, but when I press submit, it only sends it to the document on a blank area, specifially on the left corner

Comment: Don't use `element.setAttribute('value', ...)`. Use `element.value = ...`

Comment: @Barmar that actually seemed to work! Thank you!